# Generate a C++ class from an other one

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I want to generate `class Y` from `class X` :

```
class X{

  T e;
  optional<T1> e1;
  optional<T2> e2;
  optional<T3> e3;
  T4 e4;

  // Member functions
  ...
};

class Y{ 
  T  e;
  T1 e1;
  T2 e2;
  T3 e3;
  T4 e4;
  bool b1;
  bool b2;
  bool b3;

  // Member functions
  ...
}
```

So, basically I want to put the booleans of [optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) at the end to win some memory, ([this is called packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)) **You can assume that the member functions doesn't use any optional, so the generated code would be correct**, also the class can have as many optionals as possible

I know that there is no class reflexion in C++, but with Variadic Templates, it seems we can do some awsome stuff.

I have been thinking about a solution for this issue using them , but I couldn't find any. I thought someonse else may have tried something like this.

**EDIT :** 
The main goal of this is to reduce the memory of the first class, by putting the booleans of optional at the end (reducing padding), derivation won't do this, since the `size` of the `derived class` would be greater than `base class`

The code would be generated either by passing the class X as template to a generator `ClassGenerator<X>`, or maybe the generator can take more arguments like this `ClassGenerator<X, T1, T2, T3>`

Comment: You should say if you want to do a derivation or not and why. Currently, this question is rather unclear.

Comment: And I would be pleased to know why this question does not show any research effort, being unclear or not useful

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am looking for any kind of solution, if you mean Y derives from X, look at my Edit

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;) . Namely, if you want class Y, why not just write it in the first place?

Comment: I posted my real problem, reducing the memory used by optional by putting the booleans at the end, I have like 50 files of 1000 lines minimum that all have class using optionals, a generator would be helpful I think

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun _"So, basically I want to put the booleans of optional at the end to win some memory,"_ What makes you think, that would change anything, that your class may occupy less memory. Do you have any proof for this assumption?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  class `X{double d1;bool b1;double d2;bool b2;};` has size 32 bytes, while class `Y{double d1;double d2;bool b1;bool b2;};` has size 24 bytes, search for data structure padding

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Though as mentioned by others, that's not really the approach to solve that problem. I'm well informed about padding and stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To solve what problem ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun _"To solve what problem ?"_ Reducing the memory footprint of your classes. Use rather `std::bitset` or a bitfield union, to represent single bits, instead of trying to influence the order of your class member variables.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not saying that is the only solution, but since that can reduce memory, why not try it ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ bitsets reduces performances (no alignment), also, too difficult to transform my classes to something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, basically I want to put the booleans of optional at the end to win some memory,

The best way to reclaim memory is to declare them as bitfields, or to do equivalent bitwise arithmetic manually.

The problem can be solved by using variadic templates and bitwise arithmetic. To aggregate the members you can use `std::tuple`, and to aggregate the bits use `std::bitset`. From there, you can make an accessor that returns an `optional` by value.

> You can assume that the member functions doesn't use any optional, so the generated code would be correct

There are no member functions there.

You might be overestimating the freedom that C++ gives you in typecasting. You cannot cast `X*` to `Y*`, for example. Not by a long shot. (At least, not if you use the `Y*` result.)

---

Really, the hard part is that you don't have `optional` any more and you need to reinvent it. So then you need some kind of union, but individually the unions don't know how to move or destroy themselves, because they need that bit. So you can't put them inside a `tuple`, so then you need to reinvent `tuple` as well.

```
template< typename t >
union storage {
    t value;

    storage() {} // uninitialized
    storage( t in ) : value( std::move( in ) ) {}
    // Impossible to define the copy/move constructor.

    ~ storage() // Impossible to define. Destroy value or not?
};

template< typename ... elem >
class optional_tuple {
    std::tuple< storage< elem > ... > e
    std::bitset< sizeof ... (elem) > b;

    optional_tuple( std::optional< elem > ... v )
        : e{ std::move( v ) ... }
        , b{ (bool) v ... }
        {}
    }
};
```

Comment: 1  You can win a lot of memory by putting the booleans at the end even without declaring them as bitfields, search for padding. 2  I put `...` to mean that there is some member function, I didn't put them since I don't need them to explain the issue. 3 I don't see what does that have to do with the question

Comment: `class X{double d1;bool b1;double d2;bool b2;};` has size `32 bytes`, while  `class Y{double d1;double d2;bool b1;bool b2;};` has size `24 bytes`

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Fine. That's not the central problem, though.